# Group time series events into minimal amount of buckets

Tags: algorithms, clustering

I'm trying to efficiently compute events in a time series by grouping them into buckets. My goal is to have as few buckets as possible. The constraint is that events within one bucket are all within a 30 minute time window.

To get more concrete, let's assume I've got these events:

| time | event |
| --- | --- |
| 15:15 | 1 |
| 16:58 | 2 |
| 17:13 | 3 |
| 17:21 | 4 |

A naive approach to group those events into 30 minute intervals would result in these 3 buckets

```
bucket 1: 15:00-15:30 – event 1
bucket 2: 16:30-17:00 – event 2
bucket 3: 17:00-17:30 – event 3,4
```

A better solution with fewer buckets is possible though:

```
bucket 1: 15:00-15:30 – event 1
bucket 2: 16:58-17:28 – event 2,3,4
```

What kind of algorithm do I need to look for to efficiently find the fewest amount of buckets for this kind of data?

I'd prefer a fast solution (i.e less than $O(n^2)$) over an optimal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first event at time $t_0$ needs to be in a bucket. We can safely choose the bucket $[t_0, t_0+30]$, as there is nothing to gain by making it start earlier. We then move on to the next event starting at $t>t_0+30$ (earlier events fall into the bucket we chose). We once again choose the latest bucket containing that event. It is not hard to prove that repeating this strategy until all events are covered is optimal (you can do it by induction).

This procedure runs in $O(n)$ time if your events are sorted, $O(n\log(n))$ if you need to sort them first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes this solution seems fairly trivial in hindsight . Maybe due to having a background in machine learning, I wasn't really able to frame it properly. (My mind was stuck on on k-means-clustering like approaches, but that's not really what this issue was about!)

Comment: You're welcome! I think most people occasionally gets stuck on an easy problem by looking for a complicated solution :)

Comment: @Daniel You can even use the counting sort for sorting in $O(n)$ time since there are only 1440 different time entries

Comment: thanks for the hint @Inuyashayagami, but my use case also includes the date of the event, so the provided answer is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for :)